# PostgresSQL Copy a row to the same table and alter one value

Tags: postgresql

I want to insert a new row which copies the two fields from the original row, and changes the last field to a new value. This is all done on one table.

Please excuse the table names/fields, they are very long.

Table 1 - alert_template_allocations

- alert_template_allocation_id - pkey (ignored)
- alert_template_allocation_io_id - (copy)
- alert_template_allocation_alert_template_id - (copy)
- alert_template_allocation_user_group_id - (change to a static value)

Table 2 - io

- io_id          - copy io_ids that belong to station 222
- io_station_id  - want to only copy rows where the station id = 222

My Attempt

```
insert into alert_template_allocations
(alert_template_allocation_io_id,
alert_template_allocation_alert_template_id,
alert_template_allocation_user_group_id)
values 
(
    (Select at.alert_template_allocation_io_id,
    at.alert_template_allocation_alert_template_id
    from alert_template_allocations at join io i on
    i.io_id = at.alert_template_allocation_io_id
    and i.io_station_id = 222)
, 4);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`INSERT INTO SELECT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html) syntax:

[image]

```
INSERT INTO alert_template_allocations (alert_template_allocation_io_id,
                                        alert_template_allocation_alert_template_id,
                                        alert_template_allocation_user_group_id)
SELECT at.alert_template_allocation_io_id,
       at.alert_template_allocation_alert_template_id,
       4
FROM alert_template_allocations at 
JOIN io i 
  ON i.io_id = at.alert_template_allocation_io_id
 AND i.io_station_id = 222;
```